# how to get NSObject values

Tags: xcode, nsobject

I have a NSObject with 3 diferents fields :

```
Myobject : {

title : bar4343;
idUser : 4;
Type : class1;

}
```

I try to get some value doing

```
str = [Myobject ojectForKey:@"title"]; // try to get the value to a nsstring
```

I get the error :

no visible @interface for 'NSObject' declares de selector 'objectForKey'

Please, what's wrong, anyone can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like everything is wrong. The first code is some JSON or what? How did you create the class? Do you know the difference between _class_ and _object_ (instance of the class)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your code like this :

```
Myobject *myObject;

// Add code to get the object

// get some value :
str = myObject.title;
```